# Absolute summability of multiplication operators on $\ell_p$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sequences-and-series, operator-theory

A linear bounded operator $T:X\to Y$ between Banach spaces is called *absolutely summing* if for every unconditionally convergent series $\sum_{i\in\omega}x_i$ in $X$ the series $\sum_{i\in\omega}\|T(x_i)\|$ converges.

By a famous result of Grothendieck, every operator from $\ell_1$ to $\ell_2$ is absolutely summing.

I am interested in the absolute summability of the operator of coordinatewise multiplication
$$M_z:\ell_p\to\ell_{p'},\quad M_z:x\mapsto zx,$$where $p,p'\in(1,\infty)$, $\frac1p+\frac1{p'}=1$ and $z\in\ell_{p'}$. The absolute summability of the identity operator $\ell_1\to\ell_2$ implies that for every $p\in[1,2]$ and $z\in\ell_{p'}$ the multiplication operator $M_z:\ell_p\to\ell_{p'}$ is absolutely summing.

> **Problem.** Let $p\in(2,\infty)$ and $z\in\ell_{p'}$. Is the multiplication operator $M_z:\ell_p\to\ell_{p'}$ absolutely summing?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question is negative, see Theorem 9(ii) in [this paper](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/sm/sm51/sm51115.pdf) of Garling.